# Android Sync Adapter Service not calling onCreate

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-syncadapter

I am having trouble getting the service started for Sync Adapter and Accounts. The framework doesn't call `onCreate` methods.

For Sync Adapter,

I have create following components:

1. Sync Service (class that `extends Service`)
2. Sync Adapter (class that `extends AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter`)
3. Sync_Adapter.xml
4. AuthenticatorService (class that `extends Service`)
5. Authenticator (`extends AbstractAccountAuthenticator`)
6. account_authenticator.xml

And updated the entry in the manifest.xml

And that's it.

I don't see any logs reported from `onCreate` from either services. Do I have to manually start them?

Please help.

Cheers,
Raj

I have followed the documents to create

The documents I have followed to write sync adapter are: 
https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html
http://blog.udinic.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/
https://github.com/Udinic/SyncAdapter/tree/master/SyncAdapterExample

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you first download and run the [Sample SyncAdapter app from android team.](https://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/downloads/detail?name=SampleSyncAdapter.zip&can=2&q=)